# Table pagination without Javascript

Tags: html, pagination, html-table

Is there a way to implement a server-side pagination mechanism for a HTML table (no Javascript, AJAX, etc...)?

Comment: The Data in that table will be static or Dynamic...??

Comment: It might change, but I don't know how fast (may be seconds or minutes). It has to be sorted though by a column chosen by the user. P.S. The DB is Oracle. For now the only thing I can think about is simply querying the portion of the table that I need with PLSQL

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a mechanism. Since, you mentioned no server-side language, we can provide you the logic.

Lets say there are 941 rows in the table and the page size is 10. So, total pages would be 95 (941 / 10 = 94.1 and ceiling of 94.1 is 95).

For the default page (page number: 1), provide the first 10 rows and give the first number in the layout the pressed button look.

> 1 2 3 ... 95

When a user clicks on any number, behind the scene the server receives the corresponding page number, say `i`. Accordingly, the query is executed to fetch the `(i-1)*10+1`th, `(i-1)*10+2`th, ... , `i*10`th rows. Implement it manually or use the `page` function of the server-side language.